# How to clear bounty on Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a pretty high bounty in Markarth but I've already been arrested there once for a quest and now everytime I submit to going to jail, it never works. I only have the option to exit the conversation and they all come after me, or I have the option to say What's the problem?

after I ask what's the problem, I have to submit to going to jail again but it still doesn't work. It just keeps going in a circle. I can't pay off my bounty or bribe the guards so what should I do?

Comment: If you're on PC, open the console, click on a guard, and type `paycrimegold`.